# Frequency plot for Means of dice rolls

Tags: probability, statistics

Consider a fair dice being rolled for 5000 times and for each 5 consecutive rolls I take the mean and put in another dataset which results in a total of 1000 new values.
These 1000 values as said earlier are the means of 5 consecutive rolls of a fair dice and I want to visualise how the frequency plot is going to look like?

What I think is that it is going to look like almost a upside down "U: with concentrated values around the mean and a thinner and thinner tails while moving away from the mean?
Is it correct?

Comment: You can make a spreadsheet to get the probability of each sum.  In each of five columns put the number of ways to make each sum, based on the column before and adding in one more die.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, yes. You might be interested in the [Central Limit Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem) which roughly stated says that the mean of most distributions is approximately normally distributed. What the CLT suggests for your experiment is that as you increase the number of die rolls per sample mean calculation, the histogram you plot will look more and more like the classic bell-curve.

Comment: if I increase the mean from 5 rolls to lets say 10 then the curve shape is going to shrink towards the means and its head rises a bit more upwards?

Comment: Basically yes. But I think just as importantly, the curve smooths out, looking less like a step function and more like a continuous one.

Comment: @AzeemLodhi The sample mean only takes finite values so has a discrete distribution.  So if you plot frequencies of each of these values, you will see more when you increase the sample size, and the frequencies will tend to go down (the probability of getting exactly $3.5$ goes down as the even sample size increases).  If instead you use a histogram (so area rather than height to illustrate frequencies) the peak near $3.5$ might tend to go up